# pandas dataframe replace function

Tags: python

I want to replace "?" with NaN in Python. 
The following code does not work, and I am not sure what is the reason.

```
import pandas as pd; 
import numpy as np; 
col_names = ['BI_RADS', 'age','shape','margin','density','severity']
dataset = pd.read_csv('mammographic_masses.data.txt', names = col_names)
dataset.replace("?", np.NaN)
```

After executing the above code, I still get those question marks in the dataset.
The format of the dataset looks like the followings:

```
5,67,3,5,3,1

4,43,1,1,?,1

5,58,?,5,3,1

4,28,1,1,3,0

5,74,1,5,?,1
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe?  I am having a hard time reproducing your issue.

Comment: Post it in your question please

Comment: thanks! I just posted it.

Comment: I am having no issues replacing `?` with `NaN`

Comment: I used another code, which works. Just wondering why the codes in the question do not work. The following code works:                     dataset = pd.read_csv('mammographic_masses.data.txt', names = col_names, na_values = "?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inplace=True`

**Ex:**

```
dataset.replace("?", np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It works! Or I can use               dataset = dataset.replace("?", np.NaN)